# End point does not exists - AWS SNS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm getting "Endpoint does not exists" when I'm trying to register for topic from my ios project. Inside info.plist file, I set my SNSPlatformApplicationARN to the app I created in SNS console. I've been scratching my heads of to resolve this issue. I appreciate any help. This is full error :

```
016-12-11 12:52:05.534 MiGPShttps://forums.aws.amazon.com/ AWSiOSSDK v2.4.11 https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ AWSURLSessionManager.m line:212 | -https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ | Session task failed with error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=54 "Connection reset by peer" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54}
2016-12-11 12:52:05.820 MiGPShttps://forums.aws.amazon.com/ AWSiOSSDK v2.4.11 https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ AWSURLSessionManager.m line:553 | -https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ | Response headers:
{
"Content-Length" = 262;
"Content-Type" = "text/xml";
Date = "Sun, 11 Dec 2016 17:52:05 GMT";
"x-amzn-RequestId" = "xxxx";
}
2016-12-11 12:52:05.820 MiGPShttps://forums.aws.amazon.com/ AWSiOSSDK v2.4.11 https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:240 | -https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ | Response body:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>NotFound</Code>
<Message>Endpoint does not exist</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>xxxx-xxx-xxx</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Comment: Are you sending the request to the correct regional endpoint?  Each region is independent, so only the matching API endpoint will work.

Comment: I finally figure out. All I need to do is remove the app from the device, and the error is gone. But strangely enough, I'm still not getting any msgs publish from SNS console. I can see my device is registered to the particular topic but no notification whatsoever.

Comment: Is your token valid?  Also, are you using sandbox certificate?  If you import production certificate to AWS it won't send out the push notification.

Comment: I didn't use sandbox certificate at first. I was following the instructions from another poster who suggested to use the same p12 file that I used to activate push notification feature on my project. But activation does not take Sandbox certificate, and it has to be production one. But I ended up using sandbox p12 file in creating app in SNS console. That resolves my problem.